# QFutureWatcher::progressValue returns a positive integer, but the min/max are both zero

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

The `QFuture` is iterating over a bidirectional iterator, which I assume is the root of the problem.  However, the docs say that `QFutureWatcher::progressValue` "returns a value between `progressMinimum` and `progressMaximum`".  I am calling `QtConcurrent::filtered` like this:  `QtConcurrent::filtered(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), filterFn)`.

Does anyone have any idea on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this applies in your case but if you are getting your `QFuture` from `QtConcurrent::run()` the `QFuture` that is returned from that function does not support canceling, pausing, or **progress reporting**.

Comment: I'm not using `QtConcurrent::run`, but that's a good point. I'll update my question.